# Ansible: with_items over hosts in current playbook role

Tags: ansible

I am building a role that I might want to include as a dependency for multiple playbooks.  I want to support:

```
clusterA.yml
- hosts:
  - clusterA
  roles:
  - clusterA
```

Vs:

```
clusterB.yml
- hosts:
  - clusterB
  roles:
  - clusterB
```

While in either clusterA or clusterB meta/main.yml, I might have:

```
dependencies:
  - { role: commondependency }
```

Okay, while setting up commondependency I want to ssh-keyscan the other hosts in the cluster.  The cluster could be clusterA, or it could be clusterB, or it could be clusterY.  I can find tons of examples like this:

```
- name: Key Scan Cluster
  shell: ( ssh-keyscan {{item}} && cat /opt/commondependency/.ssh/known_hosts | sort | uniq ) > /opt/commondependency/.ssh/known_hosts
  with_items: hosts['clusterA']
```

But what I really want is:

```
- name: Key Scan Cluster
  shell: ( ssh-keyscan {{item}} && cat /opt/commondependency/.ssh/known_hosts | sort | uniq ) > /opt/commondependency/.ssh/known_hosts
  with_items: the hosts I am running a playbook on right now
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go, mentioned way at the bottom of http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html:

```
- name: Key Scan Cluster
  shell: ( ssh-keyscan {{item}} && cat /opt/commondependency /.ssh/known_hosts | sort | uniq ) > /opt/commondependency/.ssh/known_hosts
  with_items: "{{ansible_play_hosts}}"
```